# Tableau Running Percentage of Total

Tags: tableau-api

Let's say I have this data:

```
good, bad
90, 10
95, 5
99, 1
98, 2
```

How can I get a tableau chart with these values:

```
90/100, 185/200, 284/300, 382/400
0.9, 0.925, 0.947, 0.955
```

The general idea is `sum(good) / (sum(good) + sum(bad))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `running_sum` like this:

```
RUNNING_SUM(sum([Good]))
/
RUNNING_SUM(sum([Good]+[Bad]))
```

You should get somethinh like this (table as an example):
[image]

Or like a bar chart:

[image]